# parsing in c, failed when scanning number

Tags: c, string, parsing

folks here the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *regex_get_string(char *data,unsigned int start_pos, unsigned int end_pos)
{

#define MAX_length_regex_res 256
    static char result[MAX_length_regex_res];

    if(start_pos < 0 || end_pos <= 0 || start_pos > end_pos) return NULL;
    if(start_pos > strlen(data) || end_pos > strlen(data)) return NULL;
    if((end_pos - start_pos + 1) > MAX_length_regex_res) return NULL;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <  start_pos ; i++)data++;
    memcpy(result,data,end_pos - start_pos + 1);
    result[end_pos - start_pos] = 0;

    return result;
}

int regex_symb_pos(char *data,char *symb,unsigned int start_pos)
{

    if(start_pos >= strlen(data) || start_pos < 0)return -1;
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = start_pos; i <= strlen(data); i++)
    {
        if(data[i] == symb[0])return i;
        if(i == strlen(data)) return;
    }

    return;
}

 void parse(char *data, int split)
{
     char k[2],*p;

     k[0] = split;
        k[1] = 0;
     int pos_now;
     int new_start_pos = 0;


         while(*data != split)
         {
     //        if(*data == '\0')return;

             pos_now = regex_symb_pos(data,k,new_start_pos);
             p = regex_get_string(data,(new_start_pos == 1 ? 0 : new_start_pos),pos_now);

             new_start_pos = pos_now;
             printf("nilai new_start_pos : %d\n",new_start_pos);
            printf("data : %s\n",p);
            data++;
          }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    parse("aku:makan:ati",':'); // first parsing
    printf("\n-------------------\n");
    parse("2:capede:eke:bo",':'); // second parsing

    return 0;
}
```

the output :

```
$ ./pointer_parsenilai 
new_start_pos : 3
data : aku
nilai new_start_pos : 8
data : makan
nilai new_start_pos : 11
data : ati

-------------------
nilai new_start_pos : 1
data : 2
$
```

and the question is :
how come the second parsing is not work properly ?, is there any fault ?

anyone ?

Comment: I believe this is a question that is easily solved using a modern debugger.

Comment: what is 'a modern debugger' were you talking about ?, im really n00b around here

Comment: Visual studio 2010 or something, you can download a free version (called Express). It has a debug option.

Comment: unfortunately im on unix.... do you have any idea what suppose debugger should i use on those atmosphere ?

Comment: @capede: GDB. It should come bundled with GCC.

Comment: @you : if you dont mind, could you explain to me/us the usage of GDB in order to get failed code ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line `data++`. You move ahead one character at a time, so for your first string, `aku:makan:ati`, you move past `a`, `k` and `u` before `*data == k[0]` because of the `:`, and the parsing stops. This is accidentally three moves, which results in three fields being parsed; `aku`, `makan` and `ati`.

The second string, `2:capede:eke:bo`, only has a single character, `2`, before you reach `:`, and the parsing stops. That's why only the first field is parsed. If you change the string to `22:capede:eke:bo`, you'll see that both `22` and `capede` get parsed.

What you need to do first, is to replace `data++` with something that increments the `data` pointer appropriately. Next you got to make sure you don't move out of the string.

To make it all a whole lot simpler, I would suggest you replace your `parse` function with something like this:

```
void parse(char *data, char split)
{
  char format[8] = {0};
  char token[256];
  char *end = data + strlen(data);

  sprintf(format, "%%[^%c]%c", split, split);

  while (sscanf(data, format, &token) == 1 && data < end)
  {
    printf("%s\n", token);
    data += strlen(token) + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: sir, im having difficulities here once replacing data++ to another increment pointer, could you give sample of code at least ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `regex_sym_pos` you sometimes are returning an integer and sometimes are just returning. This is a very bad thing to do and I think the compiler should tell you so if you enable all warnings and pay attention to them.